# Connect to SQL Server from Oracle 10g

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle10g, database-link

I have Oracle 10 g and SQL Server 2014. SQL Server host name is `server8.as.local`, login - test2, passw - test2, DB - Northwind

That's what I did.

`tnsnames.ora`:

```
hsodbc =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.1.13) (PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = hsodbc))
(HS=OK)
)

listener.ora:
LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.1.13)(PORT = 1521))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0))
)
)

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC = 
(SID_NAME = hsodbc)
(ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0)
(program = hsodbc)
)
)

inithsodbc.ora:
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = mymssql
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = 0
HS_OPEN_CURSORS = 300
```

The ODBC DSN created with the name mymssql.

Also I created a database link command:

```
create database link hsodbc connect to "test2" identified by "test2" using 'hsodbc'
```

Execute tnsping hsodbc says that everything is OK.

But PL/SQL Developer to query `select * from categories @ hsodbc` displays an error:

> ORA-12154:
>   ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent